# How to test IO performed by external class?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have a simple class that writes data to a CSV file:

```
public class CsvFileWriter {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void writeDataToCsvFile(String filePath, List<String[]> data) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try (FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter(file)) {
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputFile, ' ',
                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
            writer.writeAll(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to find the specified path", e);
            throw new ProjectException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to test the method contained in this class. I found information that this can be done using Mockito. Is it so? and how can i do this?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796729/mocking-a-file-filewriter-and-csvwriter-within-a-method-for-unit-test-throwing

Comment: As you're instantiating the `Writer` inside of the method, you can't directly use mockito, but `PowerMockito` which allows you to mock constructors

Comment: Not a fan of `PowerMockito` myself.  I would separate the code that creates the CSV content and test that separately, then I would look towards Junit4's (not sure what the equivalent is in JUnit5) File and Temporary Directory rules to ensure that files are written

Comment: @Gavin Take a look at my answer for Junit 5, also it explores your idea of extracting creation of CSVWriter from this method

Comment: @andreoss I had a look, and up voted it :). Thanks for adding the code, I really couldnt remember the names of the JUnit4/5 features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Mockito or any mocking in order to test that (with exception of failure handling and logging).
You should use `@TempDir` from Junit 5, or `TemporaryFolder` from Junit 4

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

class CsvFileWriterTest {
    @Test
    void createsCsvFile(@TempDir final Path temp) {
        final var csv = temp.resolve("test.csv");
        CsvFileWriter.writeDataToCsvFile(
                csv.toString(),
                List.of(
                        new String[]{"1", "abc"},
                        new String[]{"2", "def"}
                )
        );
        Assertions.assertTrue(csv.toFile().exists());
    }

    @Test
    void writesDataToCsv(@TempDir final Path temp) throws IOException {
        final var csv = temp.resolve("test.csv");
        CsvFileWriter.writeDataToCsvFile(
                csv.toString(),
                List.of(
                        new String[]{"1", "abc"},
                        new String[]{"2", "def"}
                )
        );
        Assertions.assertEquals(
                Files.readAllLines(csv),
                List.of("1 abc", "2 def")
        );
    }
}
```

Though you might want to refactor your class in order to be more testable:

```
@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CsvFileWriter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    private final Path file;
    private final Function<Writer, CSVWriter> csvfactory;

    public CsvFileWriter(final Path file) {
        this(
            file,
            writer ->
                new CSVWriter(writer, ' ',
                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END
                )
        );
    }

    public void write(final List<String[]> data) {
        try (var csv = this.csvfactory.apply(Files.newBufferedWriter(this.file))) {
            csv.writeAll(data);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.error("Unable to find the specified path", ex);
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pass a factory method to constructor, and use it in order to mock `CSVWriter`. For example you can test that IOException is handled correcly by you class:

```
@Test
void handlesIoException(@TempDir final Path temp) {
    final var mock = Mockito.mock(CSVWriter.class);
    Mockito.doThrow(IOException.class).when(mock).writeAll(Mockito.anyList());
    final var writer = new CsvFileWriter(temp.resolve("not.csv"), wrt -> mock);
    Assertions.assertThrows(
        UncheckedIOException.class,
        () -> writer.write(List.of())
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Your answer really helped me figure out and solve my problem.